# Custom attributes in React

Tags: facebook, reactjs, polymer, web-component

"If you pass properties to native HTML elements that do not exist in the HTML specification, React will not render them." - React docs.
https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/jsx-gotchas.html#custom-html-attributes

Is there performance issues or why aren't custom attributes rendered in React?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because React designed to not pass any data to html attributes, only store data in the state or props of component.

Answer (score 0):

Try this method you can see attribute value in console on click event

```
//...
   alertMessage (cEvent){
           console.log(cEvent.target.getAttribute('customEvent')); /*display attribute value */
        }
//...
```

simple add **customAttribute** as your wish in render method

```
render(){
    return <div>
//..
    <button customAttribute="My Custom Event Message" onClick={this.alertMessage.bind(this) } >Click Me</button>
            </div>
        }
//...
```